# Solve an integral with the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

> Determine $$\int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}\,e^{\tan(f(x))}\,dx$$ (for $\dfrac \pi 2+ k\pi \not\in f([a,b])$ for all $k \in \mathbb{Z}$) with the fundamental theorem of calculus.

My solution approach so far:

Let $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}, F(x):=\tan(f(x))$. Then $F$ is continuously differentiable over $[a,b]$ with $F'(x)=\frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}$ for all $x\in [a,b]$.

I am not sure about the $e^{\tan(f(x))}$. If it didn't exist, I would just solve the integral with $F(b)-F(a)$. What do I do with the $e^{\tan(f(x))}?$

Comment: So then you have
$$\int_{\tan(f(a))}^{\tan(f(b))}e^F\,dF=e^{\tan(f(b))}-e^{\tan(f(a))}. $$

Comment: What happens if you take $F(x) = \exp(\tan(f(x)))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\tan (f(x))$, then you have $du=\frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}dx$

Thus $$ \int_a^b \frac{f'(x)}{\cos^2(f(x))}\,e^{\tan(f(x))}\,dx =\int_{\tan(f(a))}^{\tan(f(b))} e^udu$$